# Error Adding IBM Websphere Application Server V8.5 into Eclipse SpringSource Tool Suite v2.9.1

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-liberty

I tried to add the IBM WAS V8.5 to SpringSource Tool Suite v2.9.1 but it failed with following error message:

*Missing lib/features folder* when i select the C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer path in eclipse (SpringSource Tool Suite v2.9.1).

I had installed the IBM Websphere WAS Liberty Profile Adapter into eclipse(SpringSource Tool Suite v2.9.1).

Please help.

Comment: I'm tried to add the IBM Websphere V8.5 Full profile but it say cannot enable security on the server and must use the IBM JRE 6 above. Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Kindly provide help to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem but manually install the tools.

Comment: what did you do? Need help